# Guzzle remove redundant request method

Tags: php, json, api, guzzle

Is there any method for remove redundant writing request method?

so at this moment my code looks like this

```
$response['slide'] = $this->_client->request('GET', 'artikelc/slidelimit',[
    'query' =>  [
        'auth-apikey' =>    $this->keyauth
    ]
]);
$this->data['slide_grab'] = json_decode($response['slide']->getBody()->getContents());

$response['subpost'] = $this->_client->request('GET', 'artikelc/subpost',[
    'query' =>  [
        'auth-apikey' =>    $this->keyauth
    ]
]);
$this->data['subpost_grab'] = json_decode($response['subpost']->getBody()->getContents());

$response['newsone'] = $this->_client->request('GET', 'artikelc/newsone',[
    'query' =>  [
        'auth-apikey' =>    $this->keyauth
    ]
]);
$this->data['newsone_grab'] = json_decode($response['newsone']->getBody()->getContents());
```

as you can see I must rewrite the same code. can I make that be more simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is you can simplify the calls:

```
$options = [
'query' =>  [
    'auth-apikey' =>    $this->keyauth
]];

$this->data['slide_grab'] = $this->_client->get('artikelc/slidelimit', $options)->json();
$this->data['subpost_grab'] = $this->_client->get('artikelc/subpost', $options)->json();
$this->data['newsone_grab'] = $this->_client->get('artikelc/newsone', $options)->json();
```

Comment: is there any other way?